# How to export data to Excel sheet using Selenium webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to export the data from table to Excel sheet on button click, and read the data in the Excel sheet by using the selenium webdriver in C#.

Is there any solution? If there is any method, then  please write the full code here.

Comment: What you are asking is how to export data in Excel format from a web application. You'll find a lot of answers in SO, depending on how that application is written - eg is it ASP.NET or PHP? Without any details, it's impossible to give a specific answer. Also note that SO is a Q&A site for specific programming questions. "Give me the full code" kind of questions too generic for SO. A suitable question would be "How can I use EPPlus to export a DataTable to an Excel sheet ?" (hint)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot interact with Excel spreadsheets, it is a browser automation tool that can only interact with HTML through a browser.

To manipulate Excel spreadsheets you will need some code that interacts with Excel documents.